# Win10 scrapy install

Tags: scrapy, installation, windows-10, libxml2

I have python install as well as c++ complier.  When I run "pip install scrapy" from the command line it starts to install but I get a couple errors surrounding the libxml and libxslt.

> error: 'xslt-config' is not recognized...
>
> cannot open libxml/xmlversion.h no such file or directory
>
> compile failed windows C++ for python  failed with exit status 2
>
> could not find function xmlCheckVersion
>
> is libxml installed.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
```

Find the documentation [here](http://lxml.de/build.html#static-linking-on-windows)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks Rahul!